# How to have a CSV with customer, order and shipping information since a date?

Tags: database, csv, magento2.4

I'm running a Magento Commerce Cloud B2B, and I need to get a CSV list of these data below, the most important data to me is the client's phone number which is inside the shipping information since a date.

- Order information
- Client information

As I can't export a file with these pieces of information above via the admin panel, how could I do it via a MySQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script is going to help you with it:

```
SELECT sog.entity_id                    `Order ID`,
       sog.store_id                     `Store ID`,
       sog.created_at                   `Created at`,
       sog.customer_name                `Name of the client`,
       sog.customer_email               `Email of the client`,
       sog.billing_address              `Billing informations`,
       sog.shipping_address             `Shipping informations `,
       sog.payment_method               `Payment method `,
       (SELECT telephone
        from sales_order_address
        where parent_id = sog.entity_id
          AND address_type = 'billing') `Phone number`,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name)
        FROM sales_order_item
        WHERE order_id = sog.entity_id
          and parent_item_id is null)   `Name of purchased products`,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sku)
        FROM sales_order_item
        WHERE order_id = sog.entity_id
          and parent_item_id is null)   `SKU of purchased products`,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTR(product_options, LOCATE('value', product_options) + 8,
                                   LOCATE(',"option_id"', product_options) - LOCATE('value', product_options) - 9))
        FROM sales_order_item
        WHERE order_id = sog.entity_id
          and parent_item_id is null)   `Color of the purchased products`,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(price)
        FROM sales_order_item
        WHERE order_id = sog.entity_id
          and parent_item_id is null)   `Price of the purchased products `,
       sog.total_paid,
       sog.shipping_information,
       (SELECT cc_type FROM sales_order_payment WHERE parent_id = sog.entity_id) `credit card type`
FROM sales_order_grid sog
WHERE sog.created_at >= '2020-10-05 00:00:01'
ORDER BY sog.created_at desc;
```

I got orders made since 2020-10-05, you can put the query above in a `customer-data.sql` file. Then run this command below.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magentouser -pmagentopassword magentodbname < customer-company-ua.sql > customer-company.csv
```

Or

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u magentouser -pmagentopassword magentodbname < customer-data.sql | sed 's/\t/,/g' > customer-data.csv
```